# Fixing a big mistake on heroku

Tags: git, heroku

So I am trying to build my first app for learning sake on Heroku.
I accidently deleted my repository on Heroku (the app is gone), and decided to create a new one. Now I can't push to the new app, as it claims the old one was the maste

Answer (score 2):

Do a `git clone` in other folder. Look into `.git/config` and copy the `heroku` remote lines.

Then, do a `git push -f heroku master`.

Good luck!

PS: The next time, do a `git clone` first and edit the changes on the cloned repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`git push -f heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've updated your git remote per: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps#manually_updating_a_git_remote

Comment: I'm getting these sorts of errors: error: Could not remove config section 'remote.heroku' when trying to update git remote

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek in .git/config for your project - you will see a [remote="heroku"] section or there (or not) which you can delete - this is the same as doing git remote rm heroku from the command line.

Then you'll need to readd your new heroku git url (which you can get from the myapps page on the Heroku site) and then do git add heroku . Then it should all work when you try doing a push.